Blazorise Vertical Sidebar always on top and collapsed
I would like in my Blazor PWA wasm the Sidebar always on top and collpased.
I tried adding to class 'collapse' but the Sidebar disappear.
    <div class="sidebar collapse">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

I tried wid @media(min-width 2048px) on app.css but on 640px all return to default. Seems that 'min-width' is not working.
.sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    transition: width 0.3s;
}

@media (min-width: 2048px) {
    .sidebar {
        width: 60px; 
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .main-content {
        margin-left: 60px; 
    }
}

I'm really frustrated.
Some suggestion? thanks!
